# Draw constraint in PlantUML

Tags: uml, type-constraints, plantuml

How to draw a constraint like this in PlantUML

[image: Example from https://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PlantUML technique 1

There's no easy way to do this, because PlantUML doesn't give a syntax that allows to relate lines.  The best you could achieve is this:

[image]

You can achieve this by association two elements and creating a pair of the same elements, e.g. `(Account, Person)`.This creates a composite element with two line segments related by the dot. You can then relate both pairs with `...`  to get a dotted line, and name this relation by adding a trailing `: {xor}`:

```
@startuml
skinparam style strictuml
class Account
class Person
class Corporation 
Account -- Person 
Account -- Corporation 
(Account,Person) ...  (Corporation,Account) : {xor}
@enduml
```

### PlantUML technique 2

Another alternative is to use a comment box to include the constraint.  This is by the way the usual notation when attaching a constraint to an element. You can then combine the pairing techniques with a note attached to each of the pairs (source:  [this tutorial](https://librecours.net/module/bdd/mod1/pres/co/mod1c34.html?mode=html) in French):

```
@startuml
skinparam style strictuml
class Account
class Person
class Corporation 
Account -- Person 
Account -- Corporation 
note "{xor}" as N #white
(Account,Person) .. N  
N .. (Account,Corporation)  
@enduml
```

### UML Design improvement

In reality such constraints should be minimized as much as possible, because they often only hide a missing abstraction. I would therefore not use the {xor} and rather consider :

[image]

By the way, the grouping of multiple inheritance relations is also achieved with pairing, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53420903/3723423).

Comment: The dots in the association mids don't look like `strictuml`though ;-)

Comment: @qwerty_so I can only agree.  As far as I understood, this dot was initially introduced for modelling association classes (A,B) .. C and it looks less shocking in this context.  Using it for grouping specialization is already a trick that reuses(misuses?) the notation for another purpose.  On the other side, I find it sad that there is no better and more natural way to show generalization groups in plantuml...

Comment: Well, mainly it's a drawing tool. Not too bad though and certainly has its (good) purpose.

Comment: [This](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/ROwngi9044Nx_OfBgeINv0DUbSThB2p4FrWteovcTyBi10tYlnlC5Wes0vTxpd2xf5Pq2eFPqb6XZBq_dHMz5tBgESAaYu-Z5HkGT1vekUBTIzduda1Xr1c1me4amRZ1feG_vtYAcjDkQJZcyCyoijZrT-RGD2X--1f9Yan_xJxbCXFrQbHesnOetvWw4nL-SR-nF4n7iL-cFm40) is closer to OP's diagram.

Comment: The first option is "correct"